# How to use the pyhon-selenium expected condition functions directly?

Tags: python, selenium

For the python-selenium implementation you have [expected conditions](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) which you normally use within a `WebDriverWait` construct:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
```

I want to use this condition directly, without the `WebDriverWait`. But doing a simple

```
element = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
```

does not seem to work. So how to do/use it?

Comment: Why not using `driver.find_element_by_id("myDynamicElement")`?

Comment: I use that, but how to tell selenium that the element should be `visible` or not `visible` or `clickable` etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Then you might want to build a custom method to run a code block

```
def try_bool(attempts = 10, duration = 0.2, interest = True)
  count = 0
  item_of_interest = null
  while item_of_interest == interest || count == attempts
    item_of_interest = interest
    time.sleep(duration)
    count += 1

element = driver.find_element_by_id('locator')
try_bool(10,1,element.is_displayed())
```

Comment: Here you are using `is_displayed()` to check if the state of the element corresponds to the condition `presence_of_element_located`? Is that correct? If so, do you have a correspondence of each element to some element's attribute? Or better to check out the source code directly at https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html#element_to_be_clickable